# jquery timepicker только цифры

Tags: jquery, input, плагин, datetimepicker

Есть такой вопрос.

Прикрепил `jquery timepicker`, и там есть такая проблема, в `input` можно написать какие угодно символы.

Нужно что бы в нем можно было писать только цифры и конкретные символы (`:`, , `AM`, `PM`).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот и сам пример.

```js
$(function(){
   $('#example').timepicker({
        'timeFormat': 'h:i A',
        dynamic: false,
        dropdown: true,
        scrollbar: true
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/jquery.timepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/jquery.timepicker.css">
<input type="text" id="example" />
```

Comment: Может проще совсем запретить ввод чего-либо через опцию disableTextInput? Или нужно, чтобы именно сам пользователь вводил данные?

Comment: @Eleferen нет нужно по что бы по минутно пользователь мог вводить время.